# sugget me some excersise which need to follow to avoid to injury?

Tags: gym

friend, I am Trishna from India. As per my age, I am a little bit overweight that is why I plan to join the gym near me. But few of my friend teel that they get an injury when they doing exercise. I don't want any injury in my body. So if anyone suggests me some best exercise which will easy but effective as well as doesn't injure my health then it will be great for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is incredibly broad, and we have no idea of your history, tendency towards injury, etc. I will say that any exercise done improperly can lead to injury no matter what it is. I would suggest you find a trainer or someone that knows the gym and how to do the various exercises to show you proper form.